# Deploying Java app to Google App Engine with local dependencies giving ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, dependency-management

I'm making a Spring Boot application that makes use of Attribute Based Encryption, and everything works fine locally. However as the library i'm using isn't available on a maven repository I am have it added to my pom by referencing the jar directly. However when I deploy to GAE and try to use it I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.junwei.bswabe.SerializeUtils
```

Not sure why this isn't being included when I build my apps .jar, any help would be appreciated.
My pom looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unisa.dia.gas</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpbc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/lib/jpbc-api-1.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unisa.dia.gas</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpbc-plaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/lib/jpbc-plaf-1.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.junwei.cpabe</groupId>
            <artifactId>cpabe-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/lib/cpabe-api-1.0.2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I do know that using a systemPath in maven is deprecated but not sure what I can use in place of this. I've tried using what is listed here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html
However this just resulted with this error when attempting to run locally:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        BswabePub cannot be resolved to a type
        SerializeUtils cannot be resolved
        BswabePrv cannot be resolved to a type
        SerializeUtils cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked out was I was doing wrong, I still had the system in my pom after adding the jars with

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file
```

Which I guess was causing them not to be complied correctly